# Using exit() in c++

Tags: c++, std

For one reason or another, I am messing around with the exit() function in c++. I am getting all kinds of strange errors from my mac running lion (64 bit). I am compiling using `g++ -o -g -Wall`.

Exhibit A:

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main(int arc, char *argv[]){
     exit(1);
 }
```

The Terminal output looks like this

```
 $ g++ -o -g -Wall test main.cpp
 ld: in test, can't link with a main executable for architecture x86_64
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but `$ g++ -o test main.cpp` compiles fine.

using `#include<stdio.h>` or `#include<stdlib.h>` result in the same compilation error.

I am just wondering if anyone might be able to see immediately what is going on here?

Comment: Regardless of the exact problem at hand, the short answer to the question implied in the title is that you generally want to avoid `exit` in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I will use `return` in the future instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`test` is the name of the binary to produce, your first argument list should be:

```
> g++ -g -Wall -o test main.cpp
               ^^^^^^^ -o has test for an argument
```

Comment: And be aware that `test` is a built-in in many shells, so even if you have an executable named `test` in the local directory, just invoking `test` won't get it.  (You can either invoke the program with `./test`, or name it something else.)

Answer (score 2):

-o is meant to be followed immediately by the name of the output file.  It is probably trying to use your old binary 'test' as a source file, incorrectly.

Try this:

```
g++ -o test -g -Wall main.cpp
```